# Read CSV data directly from HTTP response in Android

Tags: android, csv, httpresponse

I get csv type data from the server. I use

```
response = Client.execute(httppost);
String reply= EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).toString();
```

to get the data in string. The string contains data as

```
id,name
1,Allende y Boulevard
2,Antonio Plaza y Boulevard
3,Bares Las Fuentes
4,Bares Alameda
5,Casa Salgado
6,Calzada
7,Prepa Oficial
```

I want to read this data using javacsv http://www.csvreader.com/ However it needs input from a csv file or from an inputStream. Is there any way I can write this csv data to file or provide this input to the javacsv .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parse` method.

```
import com.csvreader.*;
public class CSVReaderDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "id,name\n" + "1,Allende y Boulevard\n"
                + "2,Antonio Plaza y Boulevard\n" + "3,Bares Las Fuentes\n"
                + "4,Bares Alameda\n" + "5,Casa Salgado\n" + "6,Calzada\n"
                + "7,Prepa Oficial\n";
        CsvReader creader = CsvReader.parse(str);
        // your code
    }

}
```

As in the javadoc:

```
public static CsvReader parse(String data)
Creates a CsvReader object using a string of data as the source. Uses ISO-8859-1 as the Charset. 

Parameters:data - The String of data to use as the source. Returns:A CsvReader object using the String of data as the source.
```